# PHP Call Function on File Modification on Apache Server

Tags: php, apache

I am new to PHP and want to know how I can call a PHP function on modification of a file on my Apache server. It should be constantly listening and then call the function. I want to know if it is possible, and if it is how would I approach it?

Comment: nothing native in php to do this, it would be more of an OS side issue. if you said why, we could probably suggest another approach

Comment: I want to minify a CSS HTML or JS file if there is a new

Comment: File upload or a modification of a file.

Comment: it should be part of the development process, you don't edit the css file every hour do you?

Comment: but i would suggest a cron job running every X minutes to check

Comment: Well I use multiple computers so when I need the updated I download from my server. I hate to beautify it every time and the reminify it.

Comment: Common framework logic for that would be "compare timestamp of original and minified, if original is newer, re-minify" and do that on-access, i.e. when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To call something when a folder changes you need inotify and incron  http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en

The incron job can then execute your php script. We do exactly this when clients upload files via sftp: inotify triggers incron which calls our php to move and catalogue the new file.